# Windows C Sockets Close and Reconnect

Tags: c, windows, sockets

RELATIVE C BEGINNER WARNING!
Hi, Im writing an application in c and i am having problem with closing the socket connection with the server and reopening it again at a specific interval. Basically freeing the socket handle and re-opening the same port.  The code I currently have is  as follows:

```
int main(){

char ipaddr[15] = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
int port = xxxxx;
SOCKET s;
WSADATA wsa;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
struct sockaddr_in connect_info;
connect_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
connect_info.sin_port = htons( port );
connect_info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr);

int status = connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&connect_info,sizeof(connect_info));
send(s,"message with original socket",29,0); //send message with the first socket

Sleep(5);
//do something with setsocketopt to set the socket to not linger somehow
closesocket(s);

status = connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&connect_info,sizeof(connect_info));
send(s,"message with reconnected socket",32,0); //send message 2 using reconnected socket

//Cleanup
closesocket(s);
 WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

If possible please leave an example. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *i am having problem with closing the socket connection..* What problem?

Comment: What you show us looks fine. Can you please be more specific? What problems do you have? And in your actual code you *do* check for errors? No function that can return an error (which is just about all you call) fails?

Comment: the second message is not sent and the second connect returns -1 even though as far as i understand the socket handle s should be freed

Comment: The closesocket() returns 0 but the second connect attempt fails

Comment: Then you need to check *what* went wrong. Use [`WSAGetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the error code, and [see what it means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: change that to `char ipaddr[16]`

Comment: i just inserted xxx, the actual ip is 15. The return code is 10038, so WSAENOTSOCK, but doing SOCKET s after the closesocket doesnt compile

Comment: *error code. How would i set s to be a socket handle again?

Comment: You did it once, before connecting for the first time. You should be able to do it again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the socket again after you close the socket before you try to establish a connection.

```
closesocket(s);
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
status = connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&connect_info,sizeof(connect_info));
```